# HTTP live stream over https

Tags: ios, apache, https

I'm just having a problem with understanding if I can get Apple `HTTP` live stream working over `HTTPS`.

I want to establish a **https connection between a apache server** holding the segmented media files **and a ios client**, be able to stream content that way. i tried it with and without certificate (including a intermediate in `SSLCertificateChainFile`) but nothing works. all is fine when i use http, but if I switch to https it doesn't work.

does anybody have a running linx configuration for that?